# Change PircBot Login

Tags: java, authentication, irc

Is it possible (through some hack/cheat/legitimate way) to change the login name used with PircBot? To be clear, I'm not talking about the nickname, I'm talking about the login name, sometimes called the real name.

Comment: Trying to hide your identity, eh?

Comment: Well, no... I just don't want *everyone* to see that it's a Pircbot. Currently it logs in as "Pircbot".

Comment: Doesn't the documentation say anything about it? It shouldn't be hard to configure.

Comment: It does not, there is a setLogin method in the pircbot.jar file, however it's both protected and finalized (protected final void). However, all the methods are protected. When I try to modify it in my own java file, Intellij tells me the original is "protected". However... all the methods are marked as "protected". So, I removed the "final" and of course it gives me the same error, as that wasn't the problem to begin with. But it should be the "final" bit that prevents me from modifying it, not the "protected" bit. Honestly, I hoped for a complete explanation by someone who had done it before.

Comment: A lot of people here seem to hope for complete explanations so they don't need to do any work or research themselves. A simple Google search is usually all that's needed, but even that seems like too much trouble. You can extend the classes to access protected methods.

Comment: You can't extend a "final" method. Which is where the "hack/cheat" solution I asked about would come in. Alternatively, finding some way to unfinalize the method would be satisfactory as well. And, I did do extensive searching, though I use Bing, rather than Google. Sort of in an unending anti-Google phase. Plus I find Bing tends to return more useful things on the results page, like if a web page contains code, Bing displays the code on the results page, and that's sometimes the code I'm after, so... it's helpful.

Comment: Okay, first of all you don't extend methods. You extend classes, and `PircBot` class isn't final. Also, I found several results immediately with `pircbot realname`, so maybe you should reconsider your stance on Google.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, the answer Kayaman provided in the comments is correct. When using the PircBot library, simply extending the class enables the ability to override the required methods. As an example:

```
import org.jibble.pircbot.*;

public class BotClass extends PircBot{
    public BotClass(){
        setLogin("DesiredLogin");
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not quite what I was looking for, but searching with Google, I've found a separate bot that branched off of PircBot that does have the ability to change the login. So I'll use that. It's called PircBotX and can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/pircbotx/ for anyone who reads this in the future.